# failed to open stream: No such file or directory in tcpdf_static.php

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am going to create a pdf file using tcpdf ,i have a function

```
$test= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.'customer/invoices/';
//$test= 'http://test/customer/invoices/';

echo $test;
ob_clean();
$pdf->Output($test . $rand, 'F');
```

but i got an error

```
Warning:  fopen(file:///var/www//customer/invoices/sf_Voc_18-09-2019-12-07-45.pdf): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/customer/include/tcpdf_static.php on line 1821

TCPDF ERROR: Unable to create output file: /var/www//customer/invoices/sf_Voc_18-09-2019-12-07-45.pdf
```

please help me

Answer (score 0):

You answered your question yourself. Please check again this comment

```php
$test= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.'customer/invoices/';
//$test= 'http://test/customer/invoices/';
```

You are trying to save file to a URL `http://test/customer/invoices/`. You need to safe file on file system. Try changing line

`$test= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.'customer/invoices/';`

to

`$test= __DIR__ . '/' . 'customer/invoices/';`

Comment: thanks..got an error Warning:  fopen(file:///var/www/customer/customer/invoices/da_Voc_18-09-2019-12-26-44.pdf): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/customer/include/tcpdf_static.php on line 1821

TCPDF ERROR: Unable to create output file: /var/www/customer/customer/invoices/da_Voc_18-09-2019-12-26-44.pdf

Comment: Check if folder `/var/www/customer/customer/invoices` have write permission for the web server user. To quickly test, you can run command `chmod -R 777 /var/www/customer/customer/invoices`. Once tested, do not forget to reverse permission, if it is live server.

Comment: actualy i want server path mean hosted in godaddy

Comment: var/www/customer is my localhost path?is it same for godady?

Comment: It is most probably permission issue. To confirm, check if the code is working locally, if yes, it is permission issue on server. I never worked on go daddy server but there must be some way to give `write` permission to a specific folder.

Comment: permission is 777